# how to create a custom realted post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

In my WordPress website I want to suggest a specific post to my blog readers.
the location of the suggestion is between another post paragraphs.
for example I enter the ID of the destination post in a shortcode.
and the result would be **the title of that post with its thumbnail so the users can click on that and see the post.**

I got this code but it doesn't work. also it has no post thumbnail:

```
// Add Shortcode
function post_link_shortcode( $atts ) {

// Attributes
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'id' => '',
    ),
    $atts,
    'link-to-post'
);

// Return only if has ID attribute
if ( isset( $atts['id'] ) ) {
    return '<a href="' . get_permalink( $atts['id'] ) . '">' . get_the_title( $atts['id'] ) . '</a>';
}

}
  add_shortcode( 'link-to-post', 'post_link_shortcode' );
```

Comment: This is by default a feature in Wordpress.

Comment: choose a custom link over an `a` tag using the default link URL, here is the snapshot using an older version of the content editor [https://prnt.sc/x3q8hb]

Comment: @amarinediary as I know there isn't a default shortcode for this

Comment: @Onkar I don't want to do it manually. I need to get both the clickable title and the thumbnail just with the id

Comment: @jackpeterson do you get any error message? Or does your shortcode generate a blanc `<a href=""></a>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shortcode code is working you could get the img of your post with something like this.

```php
// Add Shortcode
add_shortcode('link-to-post', 'post_link_shortcode');
function post_link_shortcode($atts)
{
    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts);

    // Return only if has ID attribute
    if (isset($atts['id'])) {
        $post = get_post($atts['id']);
        ob_start(); ?>
        <div class="featured-post">
            <a href="<?= get_permalink($post); ?>">
                <img src="<?= wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post), 'single-post-thumbnail')[0]; ?>" alt="featured image">
            </a>
            <a href="<?= get_permalink($post); ?>"><?= $post->post_title ?></a>
        </div>
<?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        return 'No post with that ID found';
    }
}
```

You can do that or wrap all with a single link

```html
<a href="URL"> <!-- CSS display:block will help you -->
  img
  title
</a>
```

Comment: thanks it works with the title , but image doesn't appear. I think something is wrong with image src cuz I have the alt text. Html output is like this : <img src="Array" alt="featured image">

Comment: Try <?= wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post), 'single-post-thumbnail')[0]; ?>

Answer (score 1):

For the featured image you can use the_post_thumbnail_url();

```
// Add Shortcode
add_shortcode('link-to-post', 'post_link_shortcode');
function post_link_shortcode($atts)
{
    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts);

    // Return only if has ID attribute
    if (isset($atts['id'])) {
        $post = get_post($atts['id']);
        ob_start(); ?>
        <div class="featured-post">
            <a href="<?php get_permalink($post); ?>">
                <img src="the_post_thumbnail_url()" alt="featured image">
            </a>
            <a href="<?php get_permalink($post); ?>"><?php $post->post_title ?></a>
        </div>
<?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        return 'No post with that ID found';
    }
}
```